# How do I calculate tilt angle from mpu6050?

Tags: c, embedded, gyroscope, mpu6050

I am building a self-balancing robot and I have managed to configure the gyroscope mpu6050 and I now have six readings Ax,Ay,Az and Gx,Gy,Gz. My question is how do I calculate tilt angle from both Ax,Ay,Az and Gx,Gy,Gz?

Here is what I know so far, kindly correct me if I am wrong:

I can calculate the force of Gravity in G's measured in horizontal position as Ax=Ay=0 and Az=1. I use this to find tilt angle as `angle_accel = arctg( Ay / sqrt( Ax^2 + Az^2 ) )`. But I am not sure if my tilt is in Ay direction or not?

I can get the Gyro angle through integration. My gyro is read (Gx) 590 times in a 1 second period.
`float angle; //gyro angle angle = angle + Gx; //sum 590 times i.e angle += Gx*590; //END when 1 second is complete`

Will this give me correct angle?
Does the self balancing robot tilt in Gx direction?

Answer (score 1):

In a perfect world, you could integrate twice the angular acceleration. But it practice, there is an important drift: it's not working properly.

The only working solution is merging data from accelerometer, gyroscope and  magnetometer. This is what we call [AHRS](https://www.humblix.com/RxO8H4/what-does-ahrs-stand-for/). There is two working solutions :

- Kalman filter: hard to understand but reliable when implemented  properly
- [Madgwick's algorithm](http://x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/): easier to implement, but less reliable

[On this page](http://www.lucidarme.me/mpu-9250-et-arduino-imu-9-axes/), you will find an implementation (source code and example) with an MPU-9250 which is the big brother of your MPU-6050